# Is there a "quick reset" for the network connection?

Tags: wireless, gnome, networking

When I move around with my laptop I frequently need to "reset" my network connection.  What I do is

1. click on the "gear wheel" (upper right corner);
2. select System Settings...;
3. select Network;
4. toggle the setting to Off and back to On.

This works (usually), but I'm looking for a quicker approach.

FWIW, my window manager is *Gnome Classic (No Effects)*, and I'm using 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Can't you simply click the Network Manager icon and select from among the networks available at the new location, click it and connect? http://www.wireless.bris.ac.uk/gfx/ubuntu-eduroam/0.png

Comment: @chili555: i don't have that icon somehow...  i need to figure that one out...  thanks!